# send_mail() fails with privateemail.com

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

When I test this code it returns `HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')`. I'm not sure if this is the best approach for a client.

Can't I have it so the client receives the email from the senders email? Rather than using a proxy email to send to their email? That way I don't have to ask them for one of their passwords?

**forms.py**

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    from_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def contact_page(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_mail, ['mygmail@gmail.com'])
            except:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('main:homepage_view')

    context = { 'form': form, }

    return render(request, 'main/contact.html', context)
```

**main.contact.html**

```
<form method='post' action=''>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form|crispy}}
    {{form.errors}}
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.privateemail.com' 
EMAIL_PORT = 465 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'me@mydomain.com' 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'myPassword'  
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: Do you have `EMAIL_BACKEND` variable set up in your settings.py?

Comment: @azmirfakkri I don't. What do you recommend I put?

Comment: `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'` See if that helps with the error

Comment: @azmirfakkri still getting that error